# How do you get a return value in javascript from a Stripes ActionBean?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-app-engine, stripes

I am attempting to use Google's Channel API to construct a 2-player game session. I am using a JavaScript function to start opening the channel, and I have a Stripes ActionBean that opens the channel and obtains a new Token for the specific user.

How do I call the ActionBean from JavaScript and get the "String token" from the ActionBean? ${actionBean.token} did not work in the .js file.

PS: I am new to these languages and would appreciate the time and effort invested in answering my question. Thanks !

Edit: Thank you ! I have read the proposed links and I am excited about the JavaScriptResolution. How do I receive the JavaScriptResolution in javascript? Can anyone kindly provide a code snippet perhaps?

Comment: Show us your code. And remember that Stripes runs at server-side and generates text. Some of this text might happen to be javascript code that is run at client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are generating the Javascript in the actionBean that generates the page with the Javascript, the ${actionBean.token} will not work. In that case you need Ajax, you need to make the http request in Javascript. You might want to take a look at this Stripes Ajax example:

[Stripes Ajax Example](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/AJAX)

You might also want to use a [JavaScriptResolution](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/ajax/JavaScriptResolution.html) to return objects from an actionBean to Javascript, see example code:

[Amis JavaScriptResolution Example](http://technology.amis.nl/blog/1454/using-jquery-the-jquery-form-plugin-and-stripes-to-create-pretty-javascript-and-java)